# Java Absent in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I have a MacBook Air m2.
I installed android studio but not getting any option for choosing java as programming language in the dropdown while creating a new project

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project type you've selected does not support java, if you want to use Java do not use a Compose template :)

[image]

you may want to select the empty activity:[image]

and then select java

Comment: Still I am not getting that option to select java.(getting same dropdown)

Comment: when selecting the Empty views activity?

Comment: there should be a dropdown to select a language

Comment: yes, upon selecting empty view activity also getting same dropdown (without java option)

Comment: only kotlin and gradle (as in question image)

Comment: edit the question and add a screenshot please

Comment: there is a dropdown menu with a title "language", click on it please

Comment: ohh got that, and what about configuration file should I choose groovy gradle?

Comment: doesn't really matter, all pretty much work :)